# How to create ediatble form in CKEditor5 with React

Tags: ckeditor5

I created a plugin that inserts a custom react code according to the tutorial on CKEditor website (https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/tutorials/using-react-in-a-widget.html)

The issue is that when I render elements that you can interact with, it keep losing focus.

This is what's happening (I cannot click into input as it immediately loses focus):

[image: Losing focus animated gif]

This is what I use to render a simple "input":

```
DecoupledDocumentEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('.editor'), {
            licenseKey: '',
            reactBox: {
                renderer: (domElement) => {
                    ReactDOM.render(
                            React.createElement('input', { type: 'text', value: 'Hello World!' }),
                        domElement
                    );
                }
            }
        })
```